# Uploading a custom Home Page to Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

I've finally created the perfect splash screen/landing page/home page whatever you may call it for my site.

But, now I'm stuck on how to upload this design to WordPress. Because js, css images etc are in separate files & folders and not inline. So, actually how do I go about uploading this custom html (landingpage.html) and that it only retrieves the designated css/javascript/fonts/images/etc that I've created and not the ones on the site.

Answer (score 0):

Verry simpel, just create your file called `splash-home.php` in this file you add the following:

```
<?php
  /**
   * Template name: splash-home
   */
   get_header();
?>
<!-- Your custom HTML, CSS, JS here -->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Then inside your WP admin go to pages and on the right side u have an option called 'default-template' choose your custom splash template.

You can also open the `page.php` inside your theme folder to copy paste the HTML

Comment: I have a lot of JS/CSS and it would be very messy putting it into one file (believe i've tried). However, after further inspection it seems that the file getting the CSS/JS from the site and overwriting  my custom codes.

Answer (score 0):

Move all your assets like js, css to a folder like 'splash-screen'. And keep your html file top folder, Like:

- landing.html
- splash-screen

Change your html file extension to php. like landing.php

And in top of the landing.php just add this code:

```
<?php
  /**
   * Template name: Landing page
   */

?>
```

Upload all your files to your active WordPress theme folder. You will upload something like this:

- landing.php
- splash-screen (assets folder)

Create a WordPress page name Home or anything you want and set your custom template.  You are ready to go!

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work the site is all broken and takes the css of the site and not the one I've made.

Comment: Cause probably you have added get_header(); in your template. Do not add get_header(); then you it will not load css of the site.